# try/catch no switch criando loop infinito na execução

Tags: java, try-catch

Estou querendo também implementar um `try`/`catch` dentro do `while` para que quando um usuário digite um `double` com um ponto ao invés de uma vírgula, o programa aponte o erro e mande ele de volta para a execução do código.

Porém ao testar o erro, o programa entra em um *loop* infinito, apenas colocando um `break` o programa pára de executar, mas queria saber se há a possibilidade de voltar a execução do programa sem ter que executá-lo novamente.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste_Calc extends Calculadora {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Calculadora c = new Calculadora();
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n1,n2;
        double resultado;
        int opcao;
        boolean x=true;

        while(x) {
            try {
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Escolha uma das opções a seguir:");
            System.out.println("1) Somar!");
            System.out.println("2) Subtrair!");
            System.out.println("3) Multiplicar!");
            System.out.println("4) dividir!");
            System.out.println("5) Sair do programa!");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");


            opcao = sc1.nextInt();


        if (opcao == 5) {
            System.out.println("Programa finalizado!");
            break;
        }

        else{

            switch(opcao) {


            case 1:

                System.out.println("Insita o valor do numero 1:");
            n1 = sc1.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Insira o valor do numero 2:");
            n2 = sc1.nextDouble();
            resultado = c.somar(n1,n2);
            System.out.println("O resultado é: "+ resultado);

            break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Insita o valor do numero 1:");
                n1 = sc1.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Insira o valor do numero 2:");
                n2 = sc1.nextDouble();
                resultado = c.subtrair(n1,n2);
                System.out.println("O resultado é: "+ resultado);
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Insita o valor do numero 1:");
                n1 = sc1.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Insira o valor do numero 2:");
                n2 = sc1.nextDouble();
                resultado = c.Multiplicar(n1,n2);
                System.out.println("O resultado é: "+ resultado);
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Insita o valor do numero 1:");
                n1 = sc1.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Insira o valor do numero 2:");
                n2 = sc1.nextDouble();
                resultado = c.dividir(n1,n2);
                System.out.println("O resultado é: "+ resultado);
                break;  

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção invalida");

            }

     }
            }

            catch(InputMismatchException exception) {
                System.out.println("Caracter inserido não compatível!" );
                 continue;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenta mudar o valor de x para false no lugar de por o break;

Comment: Você está usando o catch com o try do menu. Tem que setar o try/catch para o trecho do código que recebe o input do seu double.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O código é confuso e por isso fica até difícil encontrar o erro, e fácil cometê-lo. É um método grande demais com muita repetição de código, mas não vou tentar arrumar isso. Pelo menos deixe as coisas mais próximas, mantenha as construções menores, não precisa ter um `try` tão grande. Na verdade eu sou crítico do uso de exceção para este tipo de coisa, mas aí é um erro da API do Java e você pode fazer pouco (até pode, mas dá trabalho demais), então tem que lidar com esse problema. Tirei algumas partes pra compilar já que não as tenho, mas essa herança parece muito errada também, apesar de funcionar. Veja como fica mais simples (eu nem sei onde estava o erro, eu só organizei e funcionou):

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Teste_Calc {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Escolha uma das opções a seguir:");
            System.out.println("1) Somar!");
            System.out.println("2) Subtrair!");
            System.out.println("3) Multiplicar!");
            System.out.println("4) dividir!");
            System.out.println("5) Sair do programa!");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            int opcao;
            try {
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                opcao = sc1.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                System.out.println("Caracter inserido não compatível!");
                continue;
            }
            if (opcao == 5) {
                System.out.println("Programa finalizado!");
                break;
            } else {
                switch (opcao) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1) Somar!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2) Subtrair!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("3) Multiplicar!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("4) dividir!");
                    break;  
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção invalida");
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Validation2.java).

Note como tudo eu faço mais próximo de onde é usado, inclusive declaração de variáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Estou com o mesmo problema! Já tentei usar break; e depois continue;, já tentei usar if/else e parar o loop alterando o boolean e depois reativando fora do loop.

Nada funcionou.

Essa é classe:

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import tadeu.fila.labs.Documentos;

public class Arquivo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Queue<Documentos> filaDoc = new LinkedList<>();

    Impressora print = new Impressora(filaDoc);

    //RESOLVER PROBLEMA COM THREAD QUE NÃO FINALIZA
    //RESOLVER PROBLEMA DE LOOP INFINITO SE DIGITAR LETRAS AO INVES DE NÚMEROS
    menu(scan, filaDoc);


}

public static void adicionarDocumento(Scanner scan, Queue filaDoc) {

    System.out.println("Digite o nome do documento:");
    String nomeDoc = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de páginas:");
    int qtdPaginas = scan.nextInt();

    Documentos doc = new Documentos(nomeDoc, qtdPaginas);

    synchronized(filaDoc) {
        filaDoc.add(doc);
    }
    System.out.println("Documento adicionado com sucesso!");
}

public static void menu(Scanner scan, Queue filaDoc) {

    boolean menuAtivo = true;
    int opcaoMenu = 0;
    while (menuAtivo) {
        System.out.println("1 - Adicionar documentos" + "\n" + "2 - Visualizar fila de impressão" + "\n" + "3 - Sair do Menu" );
        try {
            opcaoMenu = scan.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Digite apenas o número da opção desejada!");
        }
            menuAtivo = executarOpcao(opcaoMenu, filaDoc, scan);

    }
}

public static boolean executarOpcao(int opcaoMenu, Queue filaDoc, Scanner scan) {

    synchronized(filaDoc) {

        boolean menuAtivo;
        switch (opcaoMenu) {

        case 1:
            adicionarDocumento(scan, filaDoc);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(filaDoc.toString());
            break;
        case 3:
            return menuAtivo = false;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return menuAtivo = true;
    }
}
```

}

Se for necessário para entendimento, segue as outras classe:

import java.util.Queue;

public class Impressora implements Runnable{

```
private Queue<Documentos> doc;

public Impressora(Queue<Documentos> doc) {
    this.doc = doc;
    instanciarEStartarThread();
}

public void instanciarEStartarThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run() {

    boolean rodarThread = true;
    while (rodarThread) {

        if (doc.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            impressaoDocumento();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void impressaoDocumento() {

    int tamanhoDoc = doc.peek().getQtdPaginas();
    String nomeDoc = doc.peek().getNome();

    System.out.println("Iniciando impressão do documento: " + nomeDoc);

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoDoc; i++) {
        System.out.println("Documento: " + nomeDoc);
        int paginaEmImpressao = i + 1;
        System.out.println("Imprimindo página: " + paginaEmImpressao + " de " + tamanhoDoc);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(doc.peek() + " foi impresso com sucesso!");
    doc.poll();
}
```

}

public class Documentos {

```
private String nome;
private int qtdPaginas;
private boolean documentoImpresso;

public Documentos(String nome, int qtdPaginas) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.qtdPaginas = qtdPaginas;
    this.documentoImpresso = false; }

public String getNome() {
    return this.nome;
}

public int getQtdPaginas() {
    return this.qtdPaginas;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.println();
    return "Documento: " + nome + ", Quant. Páginas: " + qtdPaginas ;
}
```

}