# Menu de opções no console em JAVA

Tags: java

Ola, sou novo na linguagem, estou como estagiário em uma empresa de programação e meu chefe me pediu para realizar um pequeno programa para exercitar o meu aprendizado, pediu que fizesse um menu no console em java.

-cada item precisa ter uma descrição, exemplo: cadastros
-cada item pode ter outros itens, exemplo: pessoas, produtos.
-os itens do menu estão condicionados a serem exibidos apenas quando o usuário tem permissão para isso.
-o desafio é criar o programa para que seja possível inserir a estrutura do menu e o programa montar o mesmo de acordo com a estrutura informada.
-é necessário também uma estrutura que informe quais itens o usuário tem acesso.

Eu realizei o menu até agora, a primeira dificuldade é que eu escolho uma opção e o programa se encerra, preciso que ele continue funcionando para selecionar outras opções, estou tentando salvar o que a pessoa digita no teclado para um arraylist no caso os cadastros, a parte da permissão não faço ideia como fazer, alguém me da uma luz por favor kkkk

meu código até então:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner menu = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("##--Teste Estrutura de Menu--##\n\n");
        System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
        System.out.print("| Opção 1 - Novo Cadastro     |\n");
        System.out.print("| Opção 2 - Clientes          |\n");
        System.out.print("| Opção 3 - Produtos          |\n");
        System.out.print("| Opção 4 - Sair              |\n");
        System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
        System.out.print("Digite uma opção: ");

        int opcao = menu.nextInt();


        switch (opcao) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("\nOpção Novo Cadastro Selecionado");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.print("\nOpção Clientes Selecionado\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.print("\nOpção Produtos Selecionado\n");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.print("\nOpção Inválida!");
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.print("\nAté logo!");
            menu.close();       
        }
    }
}
```

Depois descobri que teria que usar um laço de repetição, acho que o melhor seria o do..while no meu caso, porém não estou conseguindo implementar no meu código.

```
package programaJava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner menu = new Scanner (System.in);

            do {
            System.out.print("##--Teste Estrutura de Menu--##\n\n");
            System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 1 - Novo Cadastro     |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 2 - Clientes          |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 3 - Produtos          |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 4 - Sair              |\n");
            System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
            System.out.print("Digite uma opção: ");

            int opcao = menu.nextInt();

            if (opcao == 4) {
                System.out.print("\nAté logo!");
                menu.close(); 
            }

            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Novo Cadastro Selecionado");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Clientes Selecionado\n");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Produtos Selecionado\n");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Inválida!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso que quer? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146875/101 OU isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/390450/101

Comment: `menu.close()` fecha o `Scanner`, que por sua vez fecha o `System.in`. Mas vc [**não deve fechar o `System.in`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052), ele é um recurso "especial", gerenciado pela JVM e uma vez fechado, [você não consegue reabri-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286893).

Answer (score 0):

Coloque uma "while(true)" no lugar do "do", ou uma "while" com condição.

O codigo fica assim:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication8;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Matheus Markies
 */
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner menu = new Scanner (System.in);

            while (true) {            

            System.out.print("##--Teste Estrutura de Menu--##\n\n");
            System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 1 - Novo Cadastro     |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 2 - Clientes          |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 3 - Produtos          |\n");
            System.out.print("| Opção 4 - Sair              |\n");
            System.out.print("|-----------------------------|\n");
            System.out.print("Digite uma opção: ");

            int opcao = menu.nextInt();

            if (opcao == 4) {
                System.out.print("\nAté logo!");
                menu.close(); 
            }

            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Novo Cadastro Selecionado");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Clientes Selecionado\n");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Produtos Selecionado\n");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.print("\nOpção Inválida!");
                break;
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Se digitar `4`, você fecha o `Scanner` mas não sai do `while`, e na próxima iteração `nextInt()` tentará ler do `Scanner` fechado e dará erro: https://ideone.com/iPIikH

Comment: E so adicionar um break;

Comment: Então edite a resposta e faça isso. Responder com código que não funciona não é uma boa...